# DataTable não atualiza logo após a "ação"

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee

Tenho uma `DataTable` com alguns dados quando eu seleciono uma linha da tabela e clico em clico em finalizar processo essa linha é salva em meu banco com o status `Finalizado` e o `Cargo` do usuário logado porém essa linha só some da minha tabela depois de vários `F5`ou então se eu sair e entrar na tabela novamente. Eu estou carregando os dados na tabela através desse método:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "controleAuditoriaBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ControleAuditoriaAuditorBean {
private List<SolicitacoesBD> list;
private List<SolicitacoesBD> listEnviados;
@PostConstruct
    public void carregarPesquisa() {

        try {
            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            //Se o cargo for "Liberacao" e o Status for "finalizado" faz a pesquisa.
            list = solicitacaoDAO.listarPorUsuario("Liberacao", "Finalizado");


            System.out.println("Caminho: "+solicitacoesBD.getCaminhoArquivo());
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Estou usando `ViewScoped` nesse Bean.

E é assim que começa a minha dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblAudAud" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado"
                var="controleAuditoria" value="#{controleAuditoriaBean.list}"
                filteredValue="#{controleAuditoriaBean.listFiltrada}" rows="10"
                paginator="true" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                rowKey="#{controleAuditoria.codigoBeneficiario}">
```

Será que pode ser o sistema que está pesado? Por isso que não atualiza?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que limpar sua lista porque com o `@ViewScoped` o bean é mantido até a aplicação navegar para outra página, e dependendo de como você faz a navegação ele não limpa os dados.

Comment: entendo e como eu limpo a lista?

Comment: Você pode simplesmente remover o elemento da lista. Por exemplo: `lista.remove(itemSelecionado)`.

Comment: Não deu certo, fiz algumas mudanças agora pra atualizar a tabela eu tenho que realizar a mesma ação duas vezes. Vamos supor que tenho 3 itens na tabela, eu finalizo o 1º o 2º quando chego no 3º tenho que finaliza-lo 2x. Sempre a ultima ação tem q ser realizada duas vezes